# Syncing lyrics and audio - soundcloud

Tags: ios, streaming, soundcloud

I'm creating an iphone app that streams songs using soundcloud and I want to be able to sync the song with its lyrics. I was wondering if I can do it directly through soundlcoud API, or maybe soundcloud can retrieve the song lyrics to me with time in the song for each word or sentence and than I can sync it by myself.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

yes and no.

using SC api features only:

if you have the lyrics already, you can use the timed-comments feature to add the lyrics as comments - and later display them on the right time.

but for kind of an automation, you should use services provided by third parties like https://developer.musixmatch.com